# How many events are associated with a Sample Space of $n$ outcomes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For example if $n = 2$, the amount of events that may occur is $3$:

$S = \{a, b\}$
$E^* = \{a, b, ab\}$

So what are the maximum amount of events that may be derived if the number of samples $= n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact for a sample space containing 2 possible outcomes $\Omega = \{a,b\}$, the event space contains 4 events, $ \mathcal{F}=\{a,b,ab,\emptyset\}$.

In general, for a sample space containing $n$ possible outcomes, the event space is the power set of the sample space, so contains $2^n$ events.